# .net C# post value as a querystring to another page with button

Tags: c#, submit, query-string

beginner here looking for a good way to post data from a textbox to another page as a query string

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Find a Player</h2>
        <p>
            <img alt="Find a Player" src="images/user.png" style="width: 64px; height: 64px" /><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
        </p>
        <p>
```

Just trying to get it to post to:

http:\website\depth_chart?recid=griffey

where griffey is the data that was put into the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property PostBackUrl:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" PostBackUrl="http:\website\depth_chart?recid=griffey" />
```

where the value for PostBackUrl should be changed on the client while the users write in the textbox using the `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` property:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onkeyup="alert('TextBox1 onkeyup fired');"
```

The issue you could face in mixing the javascript with the back-end asp controls is retrieving the IDs, you could solve by creating the js in the code-behind:

```
string changeScript = "&lt;script language='javascript'> function SomeValueChanged() {" +
  "document.getElementById('" + MyTextBox.ClientID +
  "').value = 'Some values may have been changed.'; }</script>";


// Add the JavaScript code to the page.
if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("SomeValueChanged"))
{
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "SomeValueChanged", changeScript);
}
```

BUT if you're trying to apply this logic to your app, forcing how an ASP.NET WebForm project should work, I can tell you that you're going in the wrong direction. It feels like there is a **design issue**.

Comment: I dont belive that will take the data from the textbox to fill the querystring